# How should the byte sequence 0x40 0x55 be interpreted by an x86-64 emulator?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm working with an emulator, and one of the binary executables I've run across has the following sequence in the beginning of a procedure

```
40 55
```

The `40` is a REX prefix, but none of the REX bits are actually set. Section 2.2.1.7 of the Intel software developer's manual states that instructions that implicitly reference the stack pointer will have 64-bit widths. Since `55` is the `push ?bp` instructions, it seems that a simple `55` would suffice to generate a `push rbp`. So why is the `40` prefix there?

Comment: Code generated by a broken assembler? :)

Comment: Broken compiler, most likely. It consistently does this in all places i expected to see `55` for `push rbp`.

Comment: After reading [Wikipedia on x86-64](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix) and Intel's x86 Reference, I would guess this to decode to `push bpl` – which I would have posted as an answer (see the Wiki page for the rationale), except that it would be an extremely odd thing to do, and so most likely my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: .. in fact, Intel's Reference does not list `r8` in the table of allowed operands for `push` (2B, pg 4-271). So it must be considered a no-op per 2.2.1: : "... If a REX prefix is used when it has no meaning, it is ignored."

Comment: @Jongware: What are you talking about? `r8` can absolutely be `push`ed, it's a `r64` to the instruction. But `objdump` agrees that `40 55` is `rex push %rbp`, where the rex-prefix is useless. `41 55` is `push %r8`, by the way.

Comment: @EOF: I provided the exact page number to indicate what I am talking about – but yes, I meant *any* 8-bit register, not Intel's `R8`. I probably should have said "*r8*" there – register placeholders are italicized in Intel's manuals. (They capitalize proper registers, so `R8` *would* indicate one of the general-purpose registers.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Jongware states in his comment the 40 REX prefix is ignored. The reason why you're seeing this however isn't because of a broken compiler, but because the compiler is following the Windows x64 ABI. Functions are required to begin with an instruction that's at least two-bytes long to allow for [hotpatching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freik/archive/2006/03/07/x64-hotpatchability.aspx). You might also see other push instructions with a meaningless REX prefix.